# i have error in my test : Expected value ['Lambda', (None, 90), 0] but i have : ['TensorFlowOpLayer', [(None, 90)], 0]

Tags: python-3.x

## UNQ_C1 (UNIQUE CELL IDENTIFIER, DO NOT EDIT)

## GRADED FUNCTION: djmodel

def djmodel(Tx, LSTM_cell, densor, reshaper):
"""
Implement the djmodel composed of Tx LSTM cells where each cell is responsible
for learning the following note based on the previous note and context.
Each cell has the following schema:
[X_{t}, a_{t-1}, c0_{t-1}] -> RESHAPE() -> LSTM() -> DENSE()
Arguments:
Tx -- length of the sequences in the corpus
LSTM_cell -- LSTM layer instance
densor -- Dense layer instance
reshaper -- Reshape layer instance

```
Returns:
    model -- a keras instance model with inputs [X, a0, c0]
"""
# Get the shape of input values
n_values = densor.units

# Get the number of the hidden state vector
n_a = LSTM_cell.units

# Define the input layer and specify the shape
X = Input(shape=(Tx, n_values)) 

# Define the initial hidden state a0 and initial cell state c0
# using `Input`
a0 = Input(shape=(n_a,), name='a0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_a,), name='c0')
a = a0
c = c0
### START CODE HERE ### 
# Step 1: Create empty list to append the outputs while you iterate (≈1 line)
outputs = []

# Step 2: Loop over tx
for t in range(Tx):
    
    # Step 2.A: select the "t"th time step vector from X. 
    x = Lambda(lambda z: z[:, t, :])(X)
    # Step 2.B: Use reshaper to reshape x to be (1, n_values) (≈1 line)
    x = reshaper(x) 
    # Step 2.C: Perform one step of the LSTM_cell
    a, _, c = LSTM_cell(x, initial_state=[a, c])
    # Step 2.D: Apply densor to the hidden state output of LSTM_Cell
    out = densor(a)
    # Step 2.E: add the output to "outputs"
    outputs.append( out )
    
# Step 3: Create model instance
model = Model(inputs=[X, a0, c0], outputs=outputs)

### END CODE HERE ###

return model
```

Comment: You have not asked a question; you have dumped a bunch of code & stated an "error" without any context.

Answer (score 4):

make x=X[:,t,:] and it will work. Don't use Lambda here as it is not needed and it may fail at the unit test checking level.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to slice the array, You may use the below mentioned lambda function, they results the same shape i.e. x shape = (None, n_values)

`X = Input(shape=(30, 90))`

`x = Lambda(lambda z: z[:, t, :])(X)`

`x = Lambda(lambda x: X[:,t,:])(X)`

Following the error, TensorflowOplayer is required by compiler, you can directly use the array slicing like numpy:

`x = X[:, t, :]`

Shape for x.shape --> (None, n_values)